# SSL connection using SSLEngine in Android Oreo and above

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, android-8.0-oreo, openssl-engine

I followed [this](https://github.com/8enet/java_security) java example to create an SSL connection between a client and a server, specifically these two files [SSLProvider](https://github.com/8enet/java_security/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javademo/http/SSLProvider.java) and [NioSSLProvider](https://github.com/8enet/java_security/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javademo/http/NioSSLProvider.java). The code works fine with Android 7 and below but with an internal implementation change in Android 8 and above as mentioned [here](https://github.com/RestComm/jain-sip/issues/170). The Handshake status is never returned as FINISHED. Therefore, my handshake is never successful. What I am looking for is an example or snippet on how to create an SSL connection in Android 8 and above.